# Symfony2 form entity class parameters

Tags: forms, symfony, parameters, controller, entity

I need an id value in my form entity and i can't find a way to get it from controller.
 I tried many options with no success also searched everywhere.
 Here is the controller code:

```
    public function addClientAction(Request $request, $idSocietate)
 {

    $societate = $this->getSocietate($idSocietate);
    //$locatii = $this->getLocatii();

    $client = new Clienti();
    $dateClienti = new DateClienti();
    $client->getDateClienti()->add($dateClienti);

    $form = $this->createForm(new FormClientiType($idSocietate), $client);
    $request = $this->get('request');



    if ($request->getMethod() == 'POST') {
        $form->bind($request);

        if ($form->isValid()) {
            // Persist objects to database
            $usr = $this->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser();

            $em = $this->getDoctrine()
                    ->getManager();
            $client->setAdaugatDe($usr->getUsername());
            $client->setSocietati($societate);
            $em->persist($client);
            $em->flush();
            $this->get('session')->getFlashBag()->set('form-notice', 'Client adaugata cu succes.');

            // Redirect - This is important to prevent users re-posting
            // the form if they refresh the page
            return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('clienti_adauga',        array('idSocietate' => $idSocietate)));
        }
    }
```

Here is the form entity class:

```
<?php
 // src/Blogger/BlogBundle/Form/EnquiryType.php

 namespace Mnv\CoreBundle\Form;

 use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
 use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
 use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;


class FormClientiType extends AbstractType
{
private $idSocietate;

public function __construct($idSocietate) {
    $this->idSocietate = $idSocietate;
    var_dump($idSocietate); exit;
}

public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => 'Mnv\CoreBundle\Entity\Clienti',
        'cascade_validation' => true,
        'idSocietate' => $this->idSocietate,
    ));
}

public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{

    $builder->add('cod','text', array('required' => false));
    $builder->add('denumire','text', array('required' => true));
    $builder->add('cod_fiscal','text', array('required' => true));
    $builder->add('cont_analitic','text', array('required' => false));
    $builder->add('telefon','text', array('required' => false));
    $builder->add('email','email', array('required' => false));
    $builder->add('judet','text', array('required' => false));
    $builder->add('adresa','text', array('required' => false));
    $builder->add('nr_reg_comertului','text', array('required' => false));
    $builder->add('cont','text', array('required' => false));
    $builder->add('banca','text', array('required' => false));
    $builder->add('delegat','text',array('required' => false));
    $builder->add('delegat_serie_ci','text',array('required' => false));
    $builder->add('delegat_nr_ci','text',array('required' => false));
    $builder->add('delegat_ci_eliberat','text',array('required' => false));
    $builder->add('delegat_mij_transport','text',array('required' => false));
    $builder->add('agent','text',array('required' => false));
    $builder->add('discount','text',array('required' => false));

    $builder->add('date_clienti', 'collection', array(
        'type' => new FormDateClientiType($options['idSocietate']),
        'cascade_validation' => true,
        'prototype' => true,
        'allow_add' => true,
        'allow_delete' => true,
        'by_reference' => false,
        'required' => false,
        ));

    $builder->add('adauga','submit');



}




public function getName()
{
    return 'form_clienti';
}
```

}

I get this error:

```
ContextErrorException: Warning: Missing argument 1 for       Mnv\CoreBundle\Form\FormClientiType::__construct(), called in C:\wamp\www\mnvproject\src\Mnv\CoreBundle\Controller\FormController.php on line 156 and defined in C:\wamp\www\mnvproject\src\Mnv\CoreBundle\Form\FormClientiType.php line 15
```

EDITED: Solution:

```
 public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
   // this was it :) 
    $idSocietate = $options['data']->getSocietati()->getIdSocietate();

    $builder->add('cod','text', array('required' => false));
    $builder->add('denumire','text', array('required' => true));
    $builder->add('cod_fiscal','text', array('required' => true));
    $builder->add('cont_analitic','text', array('required' => false));
    $builder->add('telefon','text', array('required' => false));
    $builder->add('email','email', array('required' => false));
    $builder->add('judet','text', array('required' => false));
    $builder->add('adresa','text', array('required' => false));
    $builder->add('nr_reg_comertului','text', array('required' => false));
    $builder->add('cont','text', array('required' => false));
    $builder->add('banca','text', array('required' => false));
    $builder->add('delegat','text',array('required' => false));
    $builder->add('delegat_serie_ci','text',array('required' => false));
    $builder->add('delegat_nr_ci','text',array('required' => false));
    $builder->add('delegat_ci_eliberat','text',array('required' => false));
    $builder->add('delegat_mij_transport','text',array('required' => false));
    $builder->add('agent','text',array('required' => false));
    $builder->add('discount','text',array('required' => false));

    $builder->add('date_clienti', 'collection', array(
        'type' => new FormDateClientiType($idSocietate),
        'cascade_validation' => true,
        'prototype' => true,
        'allow_add' => true,
        'allow_delete' => true,
        'by_reference' => false,
        'required' => false,
        ));

    $builder->add('adauga','submit');



 }


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you are trying to pass null to the constructor method?

I would also suggest that you pass the $idSocietate through an options array, not through constructor. The options array is the third parameter of the createForm method. And you can set the option as the required one with the $resolver.

Comment: I tried that, din't managed to make it work. Can you show me an example?

Comment: First of all thank you! I found the solution and it was so simple. I don't know if sometimes i am stupid or just lazy :)) What i need it was already there for me to take. Your answer was very helpful, after i var_dumped the $options array i've seen it :) Here it is: $idSocietate = $options['data']->getSocietati()->getIdSocietate();

Comment: Glad I could help. Remember to work with form options instead of passing variables through constructor - it can sometimes prevent you from making the form available as a service and you dont need extra properties in the form class. If it works, ok, but still I found your solution somehow weird. I never used the $options['data'], try to achieve a working solution with $builder->getData(), if the object has the id which you need.